# ExtJS4 gridPanel data not showing

Tags: extjs, store, gridpanel

I've made this very simple jsfiddle to show you this abnormal behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/mrgamer/GgUkE/2/

In my application i'm using the same methods i've written here, .loadRawData() on the store, cause .loadData() doesn't fire the 'load' event.
I'm filling the store manually cause i've to filter some JSON data, compile it, and then insert to this store.

Anyway the problem doesn't seem to be in the store, since the Grid gets populated, you can click on 2 rows, but the data isn't displayed!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

There was a typo in the **dataIndex** properties in your columns. Required a capital 'I'

**Grid Panel with Store example**

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

**Fixed code**

http://jsfiddle.net/fw3Vc/1/

Comment: :-( damn, i'm new to ExtJS4 and i was thinking model was enough...

very gentle, i used stores, but manually they seem to work fine without specifying fields

Comment: Yea it's a bit confusing. When you just define an array for the store it generates the fields from it. If you have pre configured the store you need to remember to add them in. Easy mistake to make. I've made it loads :D

Comment: @ValerioColtrè Sorry, your absolutely right! The model is enough. I've updated the answer as to the real issue and changed the code to reflect it.